# Javascript - MultiLine RegExp: lastIndex stuck on newlines?

Tags: javascript, regex

### Some Context

From [Javascript: The Definitive Guide](http://books.google.com/books?id=VOS6IlCsuU4C):

> When `regexp` is a global regular expression, however, `exec()` behaves in a slightly more complex way.  It begins searching `string` at the character position specified by the `lastIndex` preperty of `regexp`.  When it finds a match, it sets `lastIndex` to the position of the first character after the match.

I think anyone who works with javascript RegExps on a regular basis will recognize this passage.  However, I have found a strange behavior in this method.

### The Problem

Consider the following code:

```
>> rx = /^(.*)$/mg

>> tx = 'foo\n\nbar'

>> rx.exec(tx)
[foo,foo]
>> rx.lastIndex
3
>> rx.exec(tx)
[,]
>> rx.lastIndex
4
>> rx.exec(tx)
[,]
>> rx.lastIndex
4
>> rx.exec(tx)
[,]
>> rx.lastIndex
4
```

The RegExp seems to get stuck on the second line and doesn't increment the `lastIndex` property.  This seems to contradict [The Rhino Book](http://books.google.com/books?id=VOS6IlCsuU4C).  If I set it myself as follows it continues and eventually returns null as expected but it seems like I shouldn't have to.

```
>> rx.lastIndex = 5
5
>> rx.exec(tx)
[bar,bar]
>> rx.lastIndex
8
>> rx.exec(tx)
null
```

### Conclusion

Obviously I can increment the `lastIndex` property any time the match is the empty string.  However, being the inquisitive type, I want to know why it isn't incremented by the `exec` method.  Why isn't it?

### Notes

I have observed this behavior in Chrome and Firefox.  It seems to happen only when there are adjacent newlines.

#### [edit]

[Tomalak](https://stackoverflow.com/users/18771/tomalak) says below that changing the pattern to `/^(.+)$/gm` will cause the expression not to get stuck, but the blank line is ignored.  Can this be altered to still match the line?  Thanks for the answer [Tomalak](https://stackoverflow.com/users/18771/tomalak)!

#### [edit]

Using the following pattern and using group 1 works for all strings I can think of.  Thanks again to [Tomalak](https://stackoverflow.com/users/18771/tomalak).

```
/^(.*)((\r\n|\r|\n)|$)/gm
```

#### [edit]

The previous pattern returns the blank line.  However, if you don't care about the blank lines, [Tomalak](https://stackoverflow.com/users/18771/tomalak) gives the following solution, which I think is cleaner.

```
/^(.*)[\r\n]*/gm
```

#### [edit]

Both of the previous two solutions get stuck on trailing newlines, so you have to either strip them or increment `lastIndex` manually.

#### [edit]

I found a great article detailing the cross browser issues with `lastIndex` over at [Flagrant Badassery](http://blog.stevenlevithan.com/archives/exec-bugs).  Besides the awesome blog name, the article gave me a much more in depth understanding of the issue along with a good cross browser solution.  The solution is as follows:

```
var rx = /^/gm,
    tx = 'A\nB\nC',
    m;

while(m = rx.exec(tx)){
    if(!m[0].length && rx.lastIndex > m.index){
        --rx.lastIndex;
    }

    foo();

    if(!m[0].length){
        ++rx.lastIndex;
    }
}
```

Comment: You are right about your last point, I forgot to account for the last line in the string. /^(.*)[\r\n]*/gm (note the star) is better, though. Good question, thoroughly asked. +1 from me.

Comment: I'm torn on that.  Your solution is definitely cleaner, but it still skips the middle line.  It returns ['foo', 'foo\n\n'] and ['bar', 'bar'].  I think it depends what your intent is (whether you want the blank line or not).  I'll edit the question though.  Great answer too, +1 from me as well.

Comment: True, the star eats the empty line. Maybe if you strip all "\r"s beforehand, you don't have to care for them in your regex.

Comment: True, the star eats the empty line. Maybe if you strip all "\r"s beforehand, you don't have to care for them in your regex and can use this: "^(.*)\n?"

Comment: Yep, and also strip any trailing newlines.  Both of our solutions seem to get stuck on trailing newlines.

Comment: It seems to me that internally lastIndex is being incremented by the length of the string, which in the case of a blank line, is zero.

Comment: Just re-checked. /^(.*)\n?/gm does what it should, matching empty lines as well as incrementing the lastIndex property.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is that the dot in

```
^(.*)$
```

does not match new line characters, but with your `"m"` switch you make `"^"` and `"$"` anchor to new line characters. That means the "nothing" between `"\n"` and `"\n"` can be matched successfully with `"(.*)"`.

Since this match is of zero width, the `lastIndex` property cannot advance. Try:

```
^(.+)$
```

EDIT: To match the blank lines as well, do this:

```
^(.*)\n?     // remove all \r characters beforehand
```

or

```
^(.*)(?:\r\n|\n\r|\n|\r)?  // all possible CR/LF combinations, but *once* at most
```

...and just go for match group 1.

Comment: This works, but effectively ignores the blank line.  I want to match it, just not get stuck.

Comment: Changed my answer accordingly.

Comment: Edited regex #3 again to account for the last line in the string which was previously not matched.

Comment: Nice!  I don't think \n\r is ever used though.

Wikipedia-Newlines:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline

Comment: Yes, I don't either. But with custom-generated strings/documents you never know. Might well be that someone got it wrong in is app. I have to look it up often enough when using Chr(13) and Chr(10), somehow it just doesn't stick.

Answer (score 2):

The problem with lastIndex is that a JavaScript implementation that follows the standard to the letter sets it to the offset of the next character after the match.  For regular expressions, like yours, that allow zero-length matches, exec() will thus get stuck in an infinite loop when a zero-length match is found.  The next match attempt will begin at the same position, where the same zero-length match is found.

Traditionally, regex engines deal with this by skipping one character when a zero-length match is found.  Incidentally, Internet Explorer does this as well.

I've blogged about this in detail in the past: [Watch Out for Zero-Length Matches](http://www.regexguru.com/2008/04/watch-out-for-zero-length-matches/)